# Saving a datatable back to the database in vb.net and sqlite

Tags: vb.net, sqlite, sql-update

I have a datatable called DTAllCustomers which I update on a record by record basis, however I now need to change one field in nearly all records of the datatable.  I want to quickly update the database with the updated info in the datatable.
I have tried:

```vb
Dim objCmdBuilder As New SQLiteCommandBuilder(AllCustomersAdapter)
DTAllCustomers.AcceptChanges()
AllCustomersAdapter.UpdateCommand = objCmdBuilder.GetUpdateCommand()
AllCustomersAdapter.Update(DTAllCustomers)
```

Each command is processed, however the underlying database is not altered?
I have searched for some time but can't find what I am doing wrong.
Any help is greatly appreciated
Brad

Comment: What do you mean by "each command is processed"?  Do you mean each line of vb.net code executes without error?

Comment: Does `objCmdBuilder.GetUpdateCommand.CommandText` return a valid SQL command? If so, you can use ErikEJ's [SqlCE ToolBox](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ErikEJ.SQLServerCompactSQLiteToolboxforSSMS) (also supports SQLite) to test the command manually.

Comment: Have you tried inspecting the details of the `UpdateCommand` like the `CommandText` property?

Comment: Get rid of the second line.  That is the problem.  Get rid of the third line too.  It does nothing useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is the fact that you are calling `AcceptChanges`.  Once you have accepted the changes, there are no more changes, so what is `Update` going to save?  That `Update` method already calls `AcceptChanges` implicitly once it has saved those changes to the database.  It's very rare that you will have to call `AcceptChanges` explicitly.  Here are some scenarios where you might manipulate the accepting of changes.

1. When you call `Fill` on a data adapter, the method will internally add a bunch of `DataRows` to the `DataTable`.  In that case, the `RowState` of each will be `Added`, just like when you add a row yourself.  That's generally not what you want when retrieving data though, so `Fill` implicitly calls `AcceptChanges` by default.  Let's say that you want to retrieve data from one database and insert it into another.  In that case, you do want all the rows to be `Added`.  To do that, you set the `AcceptChangesDuringFill` property of the data adapter to `False`.
2. You have a single `DataTable` containing changes that you want to save to two different database tables.  In that case, you would need two different data adapters.  You would need the first `Updte` call to not accept the changes so they are still available to the second data adapter.  In that case, you set the `AcceptChangesDuringUpdate` property of the first data adapter to `False` and the changes remain after calling `Update`.  You might allow `AcceptChanges` to be called implicitly by the second data adapter or you might set `AcceptChangesDuringUpdate` on it too and then call `AcceptChanges` explicitly.
3. You have two `DataTables` in a parent/child relationship and you want to save changes from both to the database.  In that case, you need to save child deletes before parent deletes and save parent inserts before child inserts.  To do that, you would call `GetChanges` on the `DataTables` to get subsets to save in the appropriate order.  Because you're not passing the original `DataTables` to `Update`, their changes won't be accepted implicitly, so you need to call `AcceptChanges` explicitly on each `DataTable` after a successful save.

Comment: Thank you for the assistance  When I remove line 2 and line 3 I get a "concurrency violation: the UpdateCommand affected 0 of the expected 1 records"  ?

Comment: That is a different problem altogether, so you should ask a new question on that subject.  Of course, you should do a bit of research on what concurrency is and what the possible causes of a concurrency violation are first, to see whether you can tell for yourself whether you are running afoul of any of them.  We will need more information that you have provided here to determine what the specific cause is.

Comment: thank again jmcilhinney I will look further into concurrency Much appreciated